Bessel spaces and Triebel Lizorkin
It is known that bessel potential spaces $H^{s,p}$ coincide with Triebel-Lizorkin spaces $F^{s}_{p,2}$ for $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and $1<p<\infty$. Im wondering what can be said por $p=1$ and $p=\infty$. There is a nice relationship between such spaces? If not, there is some characterization for $H^{s,1}$ as an interpolation space and with the classical Sobolev spaces $W^{s,1}$ when $s$ is an integer?
Thanks in advance
